# ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, emcee

im trying too substract two matrix, first I use np.substract then I simply use '-'. the code for matrix subtraction works perfectly fine but when I input the same code to my function, python gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\emcee\ensemble.py", line 545, in __call__
    return self.f(x, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-95-627a7e4792e9>", line 11, in logposterior
    return lp +  log_likelihoodboss(theta, dataHd, covariance, BOSSDR12_z)
  File "<ipython-input-94-8ffe5ede0b1c>", line 15, in log_likelihoodboss
    ymu= dataHd-matriksmodel
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

this is the likelihood

```
def log_likelihoodboss(theta, dataHd, covariance, BOSSDR12_z):
    A, B, C, D, epsilon, rd= theta
    Hfid = 67.
    rd_fid = 147.78
    teori = []
    for i in range(len(BOSSDR12_z)):
        H = Hfid*(A*(1+BOSSDR12_z[i])**3 + B + C*BOSSDR12_z[i] +   D*(1+BOSSDR12_z[i])**epsilon)**0.5
        integral = integrate.quad(lambda x: 1/H, 0, BOSSDR12_z[i])
        DM = c*integral[0]
        kuantitas1 = DM*(rd_fid/rd)
        teori.append(kuantitas1)
        kuantitas2 = H*rd/rd_fid
        teori.append(kuantitas2)
        matriksmodel= np.array(teori).reshape(6,1)
        ymu= dataHd-matriksmodel
        chisquare= np.dot(np.dot(ymu.T, np.linalg.inv(covariance)), ymu)
        return -0.5 * chisquare
```

the ymu is a (6,1) matrix..

Comment: those are string arrays

Comment: Providing sample input for your function would help us help you.

Comment: for the dataHd it is an 6 x 1 array [[1512. ]
 [  81.2]
 [1975. ]
 [  90.9]
[2307. ]
 [  99. ]],
and which one is the strings array? because for the dataHd it is a float array,
`dataHd = np.loadtxt(filebao,usecols=[0], dtype=float).reshape(6,1)`
im not sure about the matriksmodel though, but I guess it is a float too.. because the likelihood is calculating it..

Comment: According to the error message, both `dataHd`, `matriksmodel` are string or string dtype arrays!

Comment: ok, so could you tell me how to fix it.. because I have no idea.. I appreciate your answer

Comment: How can we help you fix this if there is no context?

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. Step through the function, and verify that all values and dtypes are what you would expect.